# Compose Preview not working in multi-module but working in (:app)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

#### [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71830120/13050313) from comment by Pylyp Dukhov

---

I set compose build.gradle(:compose) same as build.gradle(:app)

#### but preview in (:compose) not showing. It looks like below.

[image]

the message bottom of preview on Android-Studio

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
> - androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
> Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.customview.poolingcontainer.R$id   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)   at androidx.customview.poolingcontainer.PoolingContainer.   ... (PoolingContainer.kt:121)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewCompositionStrategy$DisposeOnDetachedFromWindowIfNotInPoolingContainer.installFor(ViewCompositionStrategy.android.kt:97)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.(ComposeView.android.kt:123)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.(ComposeView.android.kt:392)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.(ComposeView.android.kt:388)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:131)   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)   at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:663)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505) Copy stack to clipboard

someday before, when I set `compose_version = 1.1.1`(commented) in build.gradle(:compose) it worked but after moveing git `branch` or quit Android-Studio, it dosen't today.

build.gradle(:compose)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk target_sdk

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk min_sdk
        targetSdk target_sdk

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

//    def  compose_version =  "1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0")

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.1"

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"

    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout:0.24.7-alpha"
}
```

#### This preview worked well in :app(module)

[image]

I searched and tried stackoverflow answers that related  but not found solution.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71830120/3585796) answer your question?

Comment: I believe it won't, it's a different error and at least for me it have not helped