# Cant render preview jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Ok so these are my dependencies and its corresponding value :

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
compose_version = '1.2.0'
```

and for some reason i cant render any previews whatsoever, heres the render issue :

[image]

ive tried upgrading my compose version to the latest but no luck previewing anything.

heres a sample of the preview code

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MaintenanceFullScreenComponent(
    title: String = stringResource(id = R.string.commons_app_error_maintenance_title),
    message: String = stringResource(id = R.string.commons_app_error_maintenance_description),
    onTryAgainClick: () -> Unit
) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.medium_margin)),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        LargeSpacer()
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            painter = painterResource(id = WizardTheme.assets.maintenanceScreen),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Title3Component(
            text = title, textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.medium_margin))
        )
        LargeSpacer()
        Body2TextComponent(
            text = message,
            textColor = WizardTheme.colors.grey,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        )
        LargeSpacer()
        MainActionButtonComponent(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.commons_try_again_button),
        ) { onTryAgainClick() }
    }
}
```

[image]

as you can see we have a custom theme applied to the entire project, when i RUN this on my phone ( the composable ) i can see it just fine, but not on the preview

Detailed Exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _layoutlib_._internal_.kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.classloading.loaders.DelegatingClassLoader.findClass(DelegatingClassLoader.kt:81)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.classloading.loaders.DelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(DelegatingClassLoader.kt:65)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.<init>(ComposeViewAdapter.kt)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:293)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:156)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:117)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:270)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:426)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:437)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:341)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:663)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:358)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:701)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:848)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:200)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:298)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: can you share your sample composable code please? and you need to use latest compose version rather 1.2.0

Comment: sure, i edited the post wiht it

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue with you library

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
```

replace it with

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
```

And that's It. It will work fine

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer but it didnt work senor.

i removed 
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
and left only 
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
even renamed it to "implementation" only still no luck

Comment: i honelsty think this is a doozie because ive found this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71812710/can-no-longer-view-jetpack-compose-previews-failed-to-instantiate-one-or-more-c
ive also added those implementations but nothing worked so far...

Comment: Just replace first line with given that's it. it must work try again. don't put debugImplementation rather use implementation

Comment: yes, ive tried both ways, it didnt work