# Jetpack Compose Preview is not showing when having a ViewModel parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I am using Jetpack Compose and noticed that the preview is not shown. I read articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65837989/jetpack-compose-preview-not-showing), but it seems my problem has a different root cause. Even I added defaults to all parameters in the compose function like this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalLifecycleComposeApi::class)
@Composable
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Preview
fun VolumeSettingsScreen(
    speech: SpeechHelper = SpeechHelper(), // my class that converts text to speech
    viewModel: VolumeSettingsViewModel = hiltViewModel(), // using Hilt to inject ViewModels
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController() // Compose Navigation component
) {
    MyAppheme {
        Box(
             ...
        )
    }
}
```

When I rollbacked some changes I realized that the `@Preview` does not support the `viewModels` regardless of whether they are injected with Hilt or not.

Any Idea how this could be fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack compose preview crashes with hiltViewModel<>()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053308/jetpack-compose-preview-crashes-with-hiltviewmodel)

Comment: Thanks, but regarding this article: https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-compose-navigation-architecture-with-viewmodels-1de467f19e1c  It is not the best practice to inject the ViewModels in the Composable functions.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to visualize the preview of the screen, by wrapping the ViewModels's functions into data classes, like this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalLifecycleComposeApi::class)
@Composable
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Preview
fun VolumeSettingsScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    speechCallbacks: SpeechCallbacks = SpeechCallbacks(),
    navigationCallbacks: NavigationCallbacks = NavigationCallbacks(),
    viewModelCallbacks: VolumeSettingsScreenCallbacks = VolumeSettingsScreenCallbacks()
) {
    MyAppheme {
        Box(
             ...
        )
    }
}
```

I passed not the ViewModel directly in the compose but needed functions in a Data class for example, like this:

```
data class VolumeSettingsScreenCallbacks(
    val uiState: Flow<BaseUiState?> = flowOf(null),
    val onValueUpSelected: () -> Boolean = { false },
    val onValueDownSelected: () -> Boolean = { false },
    val doOnBoarding: (String) -> Unit = {},
    val onScreenCloseRequest: (String) -> Unit = {} 
)
```

I made a method that generates those callbacks in the ViewModel, like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class VolumeSettingsViewModel @Inject constructor() : BaseViewModel() {

    fun createViewModelCallbacks(): VolumeSettingsScreenCallbacks =
        VolumeSettingsScreenCallbacks(
            uiState = uiState,
            onValueUpSelected = ::onValueUpSelected,
            onValueDownSelected = ::onValueDownSelected,
            doOnBoarding = ::doOnBoarding,
            onScreenCloseRequest = ::onScreenCloseRequest
        )

 ....
}
```

In the NavHost I hoisted the creation of the ViewModel like this:

```
    @Composable
    @ExperimentalFoundationApi
    fun MyAppNavHost(
        speech: SpeechHelper,
        navController: NavHostController,
        startDestination: String = HOME.route,
    ): Unit = NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination,
    ) {
        ...
    
        composable(route = Destination.VOLUME_SETTINGS.route) {
            hiltViewModel<VolumeSettingsViewModel>().run {
                VolumeSettingsScreen(
                    modifier = keyEventModifier,
                    speechCallbacks = speech.createCallback() // my function,
                    navigation callbacks = navController.createCallbacks(), //it is mine extension function                  
                    viewModelCallbacks = createViewModelCallbacks()
                )
            }
        }
    
        ...
    }
```

It is a bit complicated, but it works :D. I will be glad if there are some comets for improvements.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered having a structure where you have a `Screen` and the actual `Content` separated like this?

```
// data class
data class AccountData(val accountInfo: Any?)

// composable "Screen", where you define contexts, viewModels, hoisted states, etc
@Composable
fun AccountScreen(viewModel: AccountViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {

    val accountData = viewModel.accountDataState.collectAsState()

    AccountContent(accountData = accountData) {
        // click callback
    }
}

//your actual composable that hosts your child composable widget/components
@Composable
fun AccountContent(
    accountData: AccountData,
    clickCallback: () ->
) {
   ...
}
```

where you can have a preview for the `Content` like this?

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun AccountContentPreview() {

    // create some mock AccountData
    val mockData = AccountData(…)
    AccountContent(accountData = mockData) {
         // I'm not expecting some actual ViewModel calls here, instead I'll just manipulate the mock data
    }
}
```

this way, all components that aren't needed to be configured by the actual content composable are separated, taking you off from headaches configuring a preview.

Just an added note and could be off-topic, I just noticed you have a parameter like this,

```
speech: SpeechHelper = SpeechHelper()
```

you might consider utilizing [compositionLocalProvider](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=compositionlocalprovider&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safari_group=9) (if needed), that could clean up your parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, In Mobin Yardim's comment, a similar approach is suggested. But I think it is a workaround, not a solution to the problem. Because the Preview of the AccountScreen still will be broken because of the ViewModel injections

Comment: I just read the link he provided, yes its a very similar suggestion, but If I may ask, view model injections such as..?

Comment: I mean when you have this: AccountScreen(viewModel: AccountViewModel = hiltViewModel()), the preview is not working.

Comment: Ohh, that's actually the purpose of separating them, if you look carefully, the `AccountScreen` is not preview-able anymore, we created another separate composable `AccountContent` where we derive the "preview", with this kind of structure you won't need to preview composable "screens" anymore, only the "content"

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I got it. Thank you as for the `compositionLocalProvider` will check it as well

Comment: Could you provide an example of how `AccountContentPreview` will handle and pass user interactions to the ViewModel

Comment: @MeLean, if you meant [interactive mode](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling), it depends on what you would want, personally, I wouldn't expect an actual callback/click functionalities like a repository call in a preview, you can leave them on the preview empty (same thing you'll see in the examples from the link I provided) or you can make some modifications on the mock for those "interactions" such as click events. I made a minor edit on `AccountContentPreview`, adding a comment in it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I see that we should use callbacks to handle user interactions (e.g. clicks, gestures and etc. )sooner or later :D.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that enables seeing preview that is optimal during development, but not so much in production code.

Make your `viewmodel` param in your compose **nullable**:

```
@Composable
fun VolumeSettingsScreen(
    viewModel: VolumeSettingsViewModel? = hiltViewModel(), ...)
```

Then, in your preview just pass a **null** param:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewVolumeSettingsScreen() {
   VolumeSettingsScreen(null, ....)
}
```